# I am an Indian Permanent Resident of the US. I've lost my passport in India. What are the steps to replace it?

Tags: passports, india, indian-citizens, lost-documents, us-residents

I'm a permanent resident of the U.S. born in India, I am visiting my family in India for vacation. I have lost my passport in a cab. I need to replace my passport to return to the U.S.

I have checked the requirements for passport replacement on the Passport Seva website.

Since I am a resident of the United States, will they make exceptions for proof of address, as I do not have an address in India. I do however have my Bank Of America bank statment with my address. Will this work?

What other documents should I bring? I also do not have my original birth certificate, but I do have a photocopy. Will this suffice? I may also be able to get a copy of my school leaving certificate.

I'm afraid of my application being denied due to insufficient documents.

Comment: Did you also lose your green card?

Comment: Still have green card

Comment: US Driver's License?  Can you get a scan of a power bill from your residence in the USA?

Comment: Just FYI - you don't need a passport to enter the US if you have your PRC "Green Card".

Answer (score 6):

As per [8 CFR 211.1(a)](http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/CFR-2011-title8-vol1/pdf/CFR-2011-title8-vol1-part211.pdf) (PDF) you do not need a passport to enter the US, as long as you have your Permanent Residence Card (PRC, ie "Green Card").

However, the airline may refuse to board you if you do not have a passport. If this is the case, my recommendation is the following:

1. Get an (official) copy of the police report (which you must have filed already).
2. Get this copy stamped and notarized by the appropriate authorities. You may have to get it translated if its not in English.
3. On the basis of this document, request emergency travel document from the Indian authorities.
4. Carry the stamped/notarized copy of the police report; plus your report of lost passport (which you would have filed at the ministry of interior at India) to the US.
5. These documents will allow you to exit the country.

In the US, file a request for a replacement passport as your passport was lost while in India. As evidence, provide the notarized copy of documents and you emergency travel documents.

The bottom line is, you just need to exit the country - and the fastest way to do that may be with an emergency travel document; rather than trying to obtain a replacement passport.